# How to get a value from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know how I can get the parameter of my stored procedure. I'm new to ASP.Net C#.. this is my stored procedure.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[obtnCtUsuarios]
    ((@nombre nvarchar (20))
AS
    SELECT
        id, idEmpresa 
    FROM
        ctUsuarios 
    WHERE
        nombre = @nombre 
    ORDER BY
        idNombre DESC
```

And I get an error in here because I don't know how to put the parameters.

```
public List<ctUsuarios> select_ALL_ctUsuarios()
{
    List<ctUsuarios> LstctUsuarios = new List<ctUsuarios>();

    string storedProcedure = "obtnCtUsuarios";

    using (DbConnection con = Conexion.dpf.CreateConnection())
    {
        con.ConnectionString = Conexion.constr;

        using (DbCommand cmd = Conexion.dpf.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = storedProcedure;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            con.Open();                   

            using (DbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    LstctUsuarios.Add(
                            new ctUsuarios((int)dr["idUsuario"],
                                (string)dr["id"],
                                (string)dr["idEmpresa"]));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return LstctUsuarios;
}
```

This is my connection and my `ExecuteNonQuery`.

```
public class Conexion
{
    public Conexion()
    { }

    public static string constr
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString; }
    }

    //Cliente
    public static string Provider
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ProviderName; }
    }

    public static DbProviderFactory dpf
    {
        get
        {
            return DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(Provider);
        }
    }

    private static int ejecutaNonQuery(string storedProcedure, List<DbParameter> parametros)
    {
        int Id = 0;

        try
        {
            using (DbConnection con = Conexion.dpf.CreateConnection())
            {
                con.ConnectionString = Conexion.constr;

                using (DbCommand cmd = Conexion.dpf.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandText = storedProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    foreach (DbParameter param in parametros)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                    con.Open();
                    Id = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            //conection.close();
        }

        return Id;
    }
```

Can someone help me get the parameters? tHx

Comment: Take a look at the Related links to the right of your post, too. They may prove helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd.Parameters.Add(literalFromSproc, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =` will do what you want. If say you have a param in your sproc called `@Name` you would do - `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "evan";`

There are also similar variants like `AddWithValue` that would work. Check out the docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", value);
```

This is how you add a parameter to your database command, which is what I think you're asking.

Edit:

```
using (DbConnection con = Conexion.dpf.CreateConnection())
{
    con.ConnectionString = Conexion.constr;

    using (DbCommand cmd = Conexion.dpf.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = StoredProcedure;

        // here is good
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", yourParamValue);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        con.Open();
```

Comment: plx can you write the code to see it who do you just it and were :)

Comment: @user2152373 You use it where you created your SqlCommand object in that middle chunk of code. Add the parameter before you open the connection. See my edit.

Comment: thx for the help :) srry for asking that im a newbie :)!! but it really help me a lot :)

Comment: dude thx for helping me yesterday :) ... do you know how can i catch values to webforms?   i need to catch the values of a textbox and dropdownlist and send them to a web form and then send them back ?!

Comment: @user2152373 Create another question for that. =) Look into ajax if you want to handle it on the client. You can also handle events if you are doing it on the server. I personally like ajax calls.